# My permanent alias isn't working

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, alias

Sorry I am new to ubuntu, just installed it.  The version Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS.

I finally learned how to install a program called WebStorm and trying to create an alias for it.  I tried creating it under `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_aliases` and `~/.bash_profile` by reading all the other forums here but none of them worked.

I tried adding alias such as:

```
alias ll = 'ls -l'
```

as a test I tried adding them in `/.bashrc` and `/.bash_aliases` but each time when I open up my terminal it'll give me an error saying ll is not a command or something but finally adding into `/.bash_profile` wouldn't give me such error messages.

What I wanted to add as alias is a something like this:

```
alias ws = '~/Apps/Webstorm/bin/webstorm.sh
```

but when I run `ws` in terminal it says:

> ws: command not found

but if I just run:

```
~/Apps/Webstorm/bin/webstorm.sh
```

directly it'll run the program.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: No space(s) around `=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to do:

```
alias shortcut = 'long command'
```

The solution is to *not* put spaces before and after the `=`. So it should be:

```
alias shortcut='long command'
```

Comment: I just did, but still get the command not found ><" as you mentioned this is what I just did `alias ws='~/Apps/Webstorm/bin/webstorm.sh'

Comment: @Dora So is it *exactly* `alias ws='~/Apps/Webstorm/bin/webstorm.sh'`? I think add a `bash ` before `~/Apps/...`

Comment: What happens if you run `~/Apps/Webstorm/bin/webstorm.sh` in a shell?

Comment: let me use the laptop with ubuntu installed and copy past the command, but this time I only tried adding the command in `~/.bash_profile` instead of the alias one. and if I only run that in terminal, it'll open up the webstorm application which is why I was sure the directory is correct :(

Comment: alias ws='~/Apps/Webstorm/bin/webstorm.sh'

Comment: @Dora If that is now in `.bash_profile`, restart the terminal and try `ws`

Comment: I did restart :(
`et-gate@etgate-NV53:~$ ~/Apps/Webstorm/bin/webstorm.sh
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0`
this is what happens if I open it in terminal which is opening the application

Comment: @Dora Does it open Webstorm?

Comment: yes it does open webstorm after running that command, alright now this feels weird, I deleted everything in `./bash_profile` and restarted termain and tried `ll` it still worked I double checked I cleared everything in `./bashrc` and `./bash_alias` too should I actually restart the machine aand ry?

Comment: @Dora So there are no aliases and *yet* you can run aliases? *Strange.* Did you restart the terminal after deleting?

Comment: yes I restart terminal each time there's changes.  That's why I am like what the when `ll` worked, I believe there isn't a built in command named `ll` right? in terminal I always type in exit to exit the terminal then used `ctr+alt+F2` to open up new terminal to try the commands

Comment: @Dora Does the `ll` do what the (now-gone) alias meant it to do? My guess is if `~/.bash-everything` is empty - it might be reading configuration from the system-wide `/etc/bash.bashrc`. You should post this as a separate question.

Comment: alright, I restarted my pc and it seems like `ll` is a built in command? it gives a list of everything which is different from using the command `ls -l` now I just restarted and `ll` still works in terminal.  I went into `~/.bash_profile` again and added `alias wow1='ls -l'` saved then restarted terminal and tried using `wow1` in terminal and it just stays command not found again.

Comment: that's just something weird found out of no where but still why isn't the alias working :( what else can I try?

Comment: alright I was so dumb :( I shouldn't keep on trying in `~/.bash_profile` should have try the alias in `/.bash_aliases`